# net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND, no typos and files are in the same directory

Tags: javascript, html

I have an index.html file with `<script src=”sc2.js”></script>` in the head section. In the same directory I have file sc2.js that has some really simple JavaScript code I wanted to test to see what it prints. The html displays correctly in my browser, but the console says:

index.html:8          GET file:///Users/myname/projectfile/%E2%80%9Dsc2.js%E2%80%9D net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Am I missing something to make it possible to run the code in my browser? I can still run old JavaScript projects in the browser with no problems. I also tried to move the script tag around and add the full path, which made no difference. The code works in jsfiddle.net. I'm using Chrome Canary.

Comment: You are using the wrong quotes, probably copying and pasting them from somewhere. The right quotes to use in HTML are `"`, not `”`

Comment: Yeah, smart quotes won't (usually) work in code

Comment: This helped! And yes I shouldn't have copied the quotes.